# SSRS Configuration rsreportserver.config <RecycleTime>

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I was facing a problem while accessing the first SSRS report of the day taking more time. But I got to know about `<RecycleTime>`, I found below references to understand the scenario.

[SSRS Slow Startup](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2735/prevent-sql-server-reporting-services-slow-startup/)

[Speed up SSRS on the first Run](https://www.sqlrelease.com/speed-up-ms-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-on-first-run)

Still, a few things are not clear to me, could anyone please help to solve my below questions??

1. If I set 12 hours of `<RecycleTime>`, then after every 12 hours SSRS Service will be re-Initialised forcefully? Or the recycle period will be extended after every last use of `SSRS-Service`(I mean last use of SSRS report)?
2. Is there any way to stop re-initializing after a certain period of time? Or any other option to automatically call the first report after its re-initialization, so the user can access their report without slow-startup?

**EDIT:1**
Error While Executing restart service command in `Powershell`
(the Service name is correct)

> `PS C:\Users\XYZXYZ> Restart-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"`

OR

> `PS C:\Users\XYZXYZ> Restart-Service "ReportServer"`

```
Restart-Service: Service 'SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) (ReportServer Cannot open service.
Occurrence location Line: 1 Character: 1
+ Restart-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController: ServiceController)
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CouldNotStopService, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

**[Resolved]: (Edit-1) Error:**
Open `Powershell` as `Run as Administrator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The recycle time is measured from the last time SSRS restarted. When
   a recycle occurs, idle resources within SSRS are freed. This value
   can be changed to allow SSRS to keep resources for a longer period
   to prevent slowdowns due to re-initializing SSRS resources. **So yes, the recycle is forced.**
2. One way to achieve a fast startup, is to schedule a 'dummy' run of the report right after the recycle time.

Try setting the re-cycle time to 1440 minutes (=24 hours), and manually (or better still, automatically) get SSRS to restart at a preset time (e.g. midnight).

If you're running SSRS on the same box as the SQL Server engine, you will probably need to carefully monitor SSRS memory use and set a SSRS minimum working set accordingly.

To control when the SSRS recycle occurs, you can execute a 1 line powershell script from a SQL Agent job at 5:50 am say, then generate your subscription report at 6 am. This will restart SSRS and users should not see any performance degradation in subsequently generating the report. [**You will need to run PowerShell as an administrator**]

```
restart-service 'ReportServer'
```

[Building a script to restart REPORTING SERVICES automatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mariae/2013/05/14/building-a-script-to-restart-reporting-services-automatically/)

[Application Domains for Report Server Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/application-domains-for-report-server-applications?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Configure Available Memory for Report Server Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-available-memory-for-report-server-applications?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I really appreciate your help!! Finally, your idea worked!!